# Django Auth Additional Validation

Tags: django, authentication

I need compare a boolean variable when I do login (variable name: approved)

```
If variable is true: 
    login success; 7
else 
    login error;
```

I have variable stored in database.

My form:

```
class LoginForm(AuthenticationForm):
    username (...)
    password (...)
```

Urls:

```
`url(r'^login/$', auth_views.login, {'authentication_form': LoginForm},` `name='login'),`
```

Views:

```
def login(request):
    return render(request, 'registration/login.html')
```

How to change default login to allow this?

Answer (score 0):

**Limit access based on certain permissions**

There's a really nice way to check if some "test" is passed. In your example, a "test" would be if `approved` variable is `True`. You can do something like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test

def check_approved():
    # get the approved variable from database
    approved = True # or false, depends on what you read from the database
    return approved

@user_passes_test(check_approved)
def login(request):
    ...
```

So, `@user_passes_test()` decorator receives a callback which must return `True` or `False`. You can read more about it in [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#limiting-access-to-logged-in-users-that-pass-a-test).

If this doesn't help you, please elaborate a bit more on what you would like to do exactly and why this method can't help you.